# Copy/Insert Data from one Table to another

Tags: vba, excel

My objective is to copy data from table1 and insert it into table2.
I tried the following :

```
        Sub Integration()
        Dim tbl1 As Range
        Dim tbl2 As Range
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
                Set tbl1 = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange
                Set tbl2 = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2").DataBodyRange

                    tbl1.Copy
                    tbl2.Insert Shift:=xlDown

                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                tbl1.ClearContents
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        End Sub
```

But instead of copying Table1 and inserting it into Table2, it seems to copy Table2, ClearContent, and inserting it into itself with the data of Table 1.

The thing is that it runs perfectly on another sheet and it's the exact same code.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks
[Pre-Integration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDmap.png)
[After integration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbK2F.png)

Comment: When you manually click insert with multiple rows selected, excel inserts that number of rows, vba will do the same. You are inserting as many rows as are currently in tbl2 when you do tbl2.insert, instead you want to insert as many rows as you have in tbl1

Comment: I'm sorry but I really don't understand what you mean... when I do tbl2.insert Shift:=xlDown, it actually Insert the table's 1 copied cells into table 2, no?. It's supposed to be the equivalent of doing CTRL+SHIFT+1 as you can't insert copied cells into a table by right-clicking on it.

Comment: I mean what you are doing here is copying 1 row, then selecting 5 rows and inserting, so you're effectively inserting 5 duplicate rows. Both answers below avoid this, though Thomas' avoids loops, which is preferable

Comment: Thank you Hello World, for me the second code works best, but what do you mean by avoiding loops?

Comment: It adds one row at a time, will be much slower over larger datasets, whilst that's not relevant in the example you give, it is better practice in general

Answer (score 1):

Use `tbl2.Offset(tbl2.Rows.Count)` to reference the first blank row after Table2.  Next paste the contents of Table1 using tbl1.Copy `tbl1.Copy tbl2.Offset(tbl2.Rows.Count)`.

```
Sub Integration()
    Dim tbl1 As Range
    Dim tbl2 As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set tbl1 = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange
    Set tbl2 = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2").DataBodyRange

    tbl1.Copy tbl2.Offset(tbl2.Rows.Count)

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    tbl1.ClearContents
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```